# Codecademy: Taking a vacation Getting There

Tags: python

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

#Define Variable For The Price Of Plane Tickets

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    return city

    if city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222

    elif city == "Charlotte":
        return 183

    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220

    else:
        return "Not valid entry"
```

This is my current code but i'm getting an error: Oops, try again. It looks like plane_ride_cost does not return 183 when the city is Charlotte.

Anyone know how to figure this one out? It'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `return` statement 1st line of the function as below. it will work

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):

    if city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222

    elif city == "Charlotte":
        return 183

    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220

    else:
        return "Not valid entry"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement should be at the dead end of the function. Instead its returning `city` at the first line. Remove it or put it dead last and it should work fine.

A return statement returns both the variable and the control back to the calling function.

Comment: Cheers that's great advice